# Eclipse window is not fully displayed

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Some Eclipse windows is not fully displayed. Example: New project, New Class .... It is lost some of the items. Screenshot:

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: enlarging that popup doesn't help?

Comment: Did you increase font/desktop scaling in the system settings ?

Comment: Try different theme like "Ambiance" and see it it helping or not.

Comment: If it worked for you please accept, this answer, you are welcome

Comment: @markkirby: But I fix it by Scaling Factor in Tweak Tools

Comment: Sorry I did not know you had tweak tools installed I will modify

Comment: Please understand I have worded the answer for any user who finds this question and answer. The important bit is that scaling was the issue

Answer (score 0):

Did you increase font/desktop scaling ?

This can cause a difference in scale between the window and its contents, eg the window is normal but the contents are larger.

Open `system settings` and then `universal access` and turn off large fonts.

OR if you have any tweak tools unity-tweak-tool gnome-tweak-tool etc...) installed reset any scaling options you set